# A simple free MIDI implementation in Java besides javax.sound.midi: Are there any?

Tags: java, android, midi

The problem is: Android doesn't implement `javax.sound.midi`.

I need a simple free library that allows me to create simple 1-track midi files.
I searched the net for it, but can't really find anything, since everything uses javax.sound.midi .

The license needs to be one where I don't need to opensource my linked app.

Any ideas?

I also looked into the fileformat itself. However, I am totally not familiar with working with bytes, hexidecimal stuff etc.

So, other option is: are there any simple midi implementations that I can use as reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for all you midi needing android devs: check out [this Dutch university assignment](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/imp/demo/H04-3-MidiMaker/MidiMaker.html)
that contains a very very basic midi file writer. Together with [this reference doc](http://faydoc.tripod.com/formats/mid.htm) you can easily expand it into playing chords, selecting instrument etc.

It worked for me!

I do have opened a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8201) for direct streaming access to the synthesizer. If you are interested in streaming midi, please rate, star, comment there.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently uploaded a MIDI library written in Java to Google Code:

http://code.google.com/p/android-midi-lib/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

For those who come across this more recently Android does, as of API version 23, implement `android.sound.midi` which is not an implementation of `javax.sound.midi` but does have a very similar API.