# I am unable to access the library file JFUGUE.jar in eclipse android app

Tags: android

My android Project on playing piano music, so i added `jfugue.jar` to my project.
my java code is:

```
 line no:29    Player player=new Player();
 line no:30    player.play("C D E F G A B");
```

the above code is written in button onclick listener. when i am clicking on that `button` i got `RunTimeEexception`, as below:

```
  02-25 09:20:54.062: W/dalvikvm(846): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/sound/midi/Sequencer;)

   02-25 09:20:54.082: I/dalvikvm(846): Could not find method javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequencer, referenced from method org.jfugue.Player.<init>

   02-25 09:20:54.082: W/dalvikvm(846): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3600: Ljavax/sound/midi/MidiSystem;.getSequencer (Z)Ljavax/sound/midi/Sequencer;

    02-25 09:20:54.082: D/dalvikvm(846): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0011
    02-25 09:20:54.092: W/dalvikvm(846): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x1c
     02-25 09:20:54.102: W/dalvikvm(846): VFY:  rejected Lorg/jfugue/Player;.<init> (Z)V
    02-25 09:20:54.102: W/dalvikvm(846): Verifier rejected class Lorg/jfugue/Player;

     02-25 09:20:54.122: D/AndroidRuntime(846): Shutting down VM
    02-25 09:20:54.122: W/dalvikvm(846): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)

     02-25 09:20:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(846): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     02-25 09:20:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(846): java.lang.VerifyError: org/jfugue/Player
    02-25 09:20:54.152: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at com.example.xyz.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)
```

Answer (score 3):

I never used jFugue, but it looks like your problem is that Android doesn't implement javax.sound.midi. So you need to find/develop an implementation of this package.

Here are some options discussed: [A simple free MIDI implementation in Java besides javax.sound.midi: Are there any?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758255/a-simple-free-midi-implementation-in-java-besides-javax-sound-midi-are-there-an)

Comment: Did you manage to get jFugue to work?
What implementation of javax/sound/midi/Sequencer did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Where have you inserted your jar file.?
Also please check if you have build the jar file.

Comment: After adding just clean the project and again build.